# Providing password using a variable to become a sudo user in Jenkins

Tags: bash, unix, jenkins, ssh, expect

I have a jenkins job, which has its own set of build servers. The process which i follow is building applications on the jenkins build server and then I use "send files or execute commands over ssh" to copy my build and deploy the same using a shell script.

As a part of the deployment commands, I have quite a few steps to be done, like mkdir, tar -xzvf etc.I want to execute these deployment steps with a specific user "K". But when i type the sudo su - k command, the jenkins job fails because i am unable to feed the password to it.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su - K << \EOF
cd /DIR1/DIR2;
cp ~/MY_APP.war .
mkdir DIR 3
tar -xzvf MY_APP.war
EOF
```

To handle that, I used a PASSWORD parameter and made the build as parameterized, so that i can use the same PASSWORD in the shell script.

I have tried to use Expect, but looks like commands like cd, tar -xzvf are not working inside it and even if they work they will not be executed with the K as a user since the terminal may expire(please correct if wrong).

```
export $PASSWORD
/usr/bin/expect << EOD
spawn sudo su - k
expect "password for K"
send -- "$PASSWORD"
cd /DIR1/DIR2;
cp ~/MY_APP.war .
mkdir DIR 3
tar -xzvf MY_APP.war
EOD
```

Note: I do not have the root access to the servers and hence cannot tweak the host key files. Is there a work around for this problem?

Comment: [You are not supposed to `export $variable`. You should `export variable`.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2163)

Comment: You should use `send -- "$PASSWORD\r"` to ensure carriage return

Comment: `sudo` reads from standard input if you give it the `-S` option.

Comment: The problem with expect is all the commands which i mentioned like cd, tar -xzvf are not working in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you get it working, having passwords in scripts or on the command line probably is not ideal from a security standpoint.  Two things I would suggest :

1) Use a public SSH key owned by the user on your initiating system as an authorized key on the remote system to allow logging as the intended user on the remote system without a password.  You should have all you need to do that (no root access required, only to the users you already use on each system).

2) Set-up the "sudoers" file on the remote system so that the user you log in as is allowed to perform the commands you need as the required user.  You would need the system administrator help for that.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
SUDO_PASSWORD=TheSudoPassword
...
ssh kilroy@somehost "echo $SUDO_PASSWORD | sudo -S some_root_command"
```

**Later**

> How can i use this in the 1st snippet?

Write a file:

**deploy.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /DIR1/DIR2
cp ~/MY_APP.war .
mkdir DIR 3
tar -xzvf MY_APP.war
```

Then:

```
chmod +x deploy.sh
scp deploy.sh kilroy@somehost:~
ssh kilroy@somehost "echo $SUDO_PASSWORD | sudo -S ./deploy.sh"
```